# is it possible to put an image inside another image and resize it always to a certain dimension?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm using opencv. The problem is this:

I have a window where I'm displaying an Image A. I have an image B coming from a videocamera, that has every time different dimensions/resolutions. Is it possible to display this image (like paste it) in another image but always inside a certain area, auto-resizing it if too small or too big to that precise area (a rectangle)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if A has a ROI, then `cvResize(B, A)` will "paste" B into the ROI in A, scaling and stretching it to fit.

Comment: this seems really cool! I'm going to try it right now! thank you!

Comment: What kind of errors? It is assumed here (by cvResize()) that both A and B are of the same depth and the same number of channels.

Comment: no they aren't.. is this a problem? one is 8bit depth x 3 channel, the other is just Black and white

Comment: The must both be of the same depth and number of channels.